# Python Service : HANA : hdbcli.dbapi.IntegrityError: (301, &#34;unique constraint violated : Error occurs only when record is entered via Service URL

Tags: python, hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying to save records to a HANA table via a python service. When I hit the URL via postman I am getting the following error even when values are not duplicated:

> hdbcli.dbapi.IntegrityError: (301, "unique constraint violated: Table(______),
>
> Index(*SYS_TREE_CS*#161833_#0_#P0) with error: unique constraint violation in self check for table
>
> H00::DST:en, constraint='GUID',
>
> udiv='3742414332314339343333314544453933413032354543414933353530343031', pos=2942321;
> indexname=*SYS_TREE_CS*#161833_#0_#P0")
> // Werkzeug Debugger

However, if I try to insert the same value directly via insert statement then its successful.

I have checked the DB using following query :

```
 SELECT GUID,  COUNT(GUID) AS NumOccurrences
        FROM Table_Name
        GROUP BY GUID
        HAVING ( COUNT(GUID) > 1 )
```

and it does not have duplicate records as well.

Appreciate any suggestions/ inputs.

Comment: You may want to share the code that inserts/updates the data in HANA - just based on the error message all one can say is: HANA processed the unique constraint correctly and prevented duplicates for the GUID field. 
This is also the reason for why you won't find any duplicates with your SELECT statement; the attempt to create them was prevented.